# BigQuery - Average session duration with hit level metrics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am trying to select average session duration by customer number (custom dimension) and page hostname.

When I run the code below, it returns a much higher session duration than I see in Google Analytics.

However, when I remove hostname, the numbers are correct.

Can someone explain why that is and if it's just an issue with my code or there's simply no way of doing this?

Thanks

```
WITH X AS
(
SELECT 
AVG(TOTALS.TIMEONSITE) AS AVG_SESSION_DURATION,
(SELECT VALUE FROM T.CUSTOMDIMENSIONS WHERE INDEX=4) AS CUSTOMER_NUMBER,
H.PAGE.HOSTNAME AS HOSTNAME
FROM `ga-blablabla.ga_sessions_20200323` T
, T.HITS AS H
GROUP BY
CUSTOMER_NUMBER
, HOSTNAME
)
SELECT AVG(AVG_SESSION_DURATION) FROM X WHERE CUSTOMER_NUMBER='xyz'
```

Comment: Hi Jurij, may you share a dummy table you are sourcing from so I can understand its structure?

Comment: Hi @federico here https://www.bounteous.com/sites/default/files/luna-migrate/BQ-Rows-2-e1462998313180.png you can find the schema. Hostname is nested into Hits->Page while timeonsite is under Totals

Comment: Hi Jurij, Neither Hostname nor timeonsite appear in your schema. It would be useful to have the schema from your bigquery tables (or the DML used to create the tables). Moreover, I would also ask you a dummy input data and what you expect/what you get from it. Right now this issue is not reproducible.